# How to change the default version of java by command line in Manjaro?

Tags: java, version, manjaro

I use Manjaro operating system
I have installed OpenJDK version 11 and 18 (version 11 is installed first) and when I type java --version command in terminal it shows version 11.

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.15+3, mixed mode)
```

How should I change the default Java version?
Is it possible to install update-alternatives on Manjaro?

Answer (score 37):

in archlinux based distros you could use `archlinux-java` instead of `update-alternatives`.

use `archlinux-java status` to view the list of installed java versions and default one; then use `archlinux-java set <JAVA_ENV>`.

Comment: There is also `archlinux-java fix` that fixes default Java environment configuration. Should be run with `sudo` though.